# jQuery UI Accordion doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have download and install the jQuery UI 1.8.17 and I try to apply the Accordion, but with no luck.

My code is the following:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document Title</title>
    <link href="../../css/tinyMCE/jquery_ui_wp_theme/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shortcodes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="codes">
        <h3><a href="#">Shortcode name</a></h3>
        <div><p>Dialog content</p></div>
        <h3><a href="#">Shortcode name</a></h3>
        <div><p>Dialog content</p></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($)
    {        
        $('#codes').accordion();
    }
);
```

The problem with the above code is that, while the accordion is rendered properly, is not functional at all. That means, that when I click on a accordion panel header, there is no any action.

Also In my console I don't get any JavaScript error, and also all the files are loaded normally. Any idea on how to solve that problem ?!

[This is the accordion as it is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Yzx.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any other scripts or JavaScript libraries, plug-ins on the page?

Comment: I don't use any other plugin. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the `$` in your ready function signature:

```
jQuery(document).ready( 
    function() 
    {         
        $('#codes').accordion(); 
    } 
);
```

You've probably copied this pattern from a plugin source, where it's generally used to ensure the plugin is using `$` from jQuery and not e.g. prototype - you declare your plugin as an anonymous function then call it immediately passing a jQuery object. If the ready function accepts a parameter (I'm not sure it does, but [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) suggest it's a regular bound event) it'll be an event object and not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery’s case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of $ back to the other library with a call to jQuery.noConflict();

see example here :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($)
{
   $('#codes').accordion(); 
})
(jQuery);
```

Comment: The problme is not the $ symbol. I don't get any error in my Console !! And the plugin is rendered normaly. The problem is that is not functional

Comment: use that one code i share here and it's working http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/cPGFE/